# Does the backend matter for savefig

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a script which plots some pandas data, and then either shows the plot interactively with `plt.show()`, or saves it to a file with `plt.savefig(args.out)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set up the dataframe here

ax = df.plot.line(x=0, title=args.title, figsize=(12,8), grid=True, **kwargs)

if (args.out):
    vprint("Saving figure to ", args.out, "...")
    plt.savefig(args.out)
else:
    vprint("Showing interactive plot...")
    plt.show()
```

The question is, does the default matplotlib backend matter for the scenario where I save to a file with `savefig`? It definitely matters in the other case since it's used to display the interactive plot, but if I call `savefig` is another backend used entirely?

Answer (score 2):

When showing a figure, the backend obviously matters, because it provides two things:

- The renderer to draw the image
- The GUI within which the image is shown.

When saving a figure, only the former matters. However, matplotlib provides a multitude of export formats. At the end, the chosen backend will determine what to do when a figure is saved, and in most cases, will use one of the existing non-interactive backends to produce the output file.

Some examples:

`TkAgg` will use the tkinter GUI to show a figure. For saving a png figure, it will fall back to the basic `Agg` backend to produce the png file. For saving an svg file, it will fall back to the `svg` backend, for saving a `pdf` it will fallback to the `pdf` backend, etc.

`TkCairo`, will use the tkinter GUI to show a figure. For saving a png figure, it will fall back to the basic `Cairo` backend to produce the png file. For the rest, same as above.

`Qt5Agg` will use the PyQt GUI to show a figure. For png will fall back to `Agg`. For others same as above.

similar for other backends.